# Forecasting with a small dataset

Tags: r

I am trying to get some forecast (5 years more) from a small dataset that is as follows:

```
year    euro
2010    17,785
2011    17,515
2012    16,880
2013    18,036
2014    18,400
2015    18,211
2016    18,382
2017    22,248
```

I've tried with ARIMA and auto.arima, for example:

```
mydata$`euro` <- ts(mydata$`euro`, frequency=1, start = c(2010, 1))
> plot(mydata$`euro`)
> autoarima1 <- auto.arima(mydata$`euro`)
> forecast1 <- forecast(autoarima1, h=5)
> forecast1
> plot(forecast1)
```

However, nothing makes sense as it forecast a unique same value for the future.

Comment: It's because with that sample size, the best choice for your estimated parameter is the inconditional mean. Therefore, your best forecast, at each h you choose, is the inconditional mean. That´s why you get `mean(mydata$euro) ` as your estimated model and forecast.

Comment: Thank you Jilber, I figured it out by doing some research. Do you think it is very incorrect to use a linear forecast with excel?

Comment: I recommend to ask this question on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ which is a better place for such a discussion